# Write to file using form input PHP

Tags: php, forms, file-handling, file-writing

The object of the project I'm doing involves making different PHP forms to create, write to, read, and delete files. This (insert.php) is my 'write to' page, and opens the file properly, but when the 'fileInsert' button is pressed, it refreshed the page and closes the open file before writing or displaying the success message. Any help or suggestions are appreciated

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>File Creator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>File Creator</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="fileName">Enter the name of the file you would like to open including the extension:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="fileName"><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Open File" name="fileOpen">
        </form>
    </body>

    <?php

    

    if(isset($_POST['fileOpen'])) {

        $fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
        echo str_ireplace("None", $fileName, "<h3>Currently open: None</h3><br />");

        if (is_file($fileName)) {
            echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
            echo "<label for='fileInput'>File is open!<br />Insert up to 40 characters:</label><br />";
            echo "<input type='text' name='fileInput' maxlength='40'><br />";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='fileInsert'><br /><br />";
            echo "</form>";

            if(isset($_POST['fileInsert'])) {

                $fileInput = $_POST['fileInput'];

                $myfile = fopen($fileName, "w");

                fwrite($myfile, $fileInput);
                fclose($myfile);

                echo "Done! <br />";
            
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "File does not exist. <br /><br />";

            echo "<a href='start.php'><button>Return to Homepage</button></a>";
        }
        
    }

    else {
        echo "<h3>Currently open: None</h3><br />";
    }

    ?>

</html>```
````

Comment: `fileOpen` and `fileInsert` can't both be set, they are on different forms submitted at different times.  You either need one form with filename and input or a two step process where the second step opens and writes.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a form is posted to the same page or to any other... we only have the last post data in the $_POST.

It's very simple... since you are submitting another form in the same page... the 2nd submit reloads the page again... but now... there is nothing to handle in the $_POST['fileOpen'] since the 2nd post contains only the 2nd post data so here is a fixed version for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>File Creator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>File Creator</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="fileName">Enter the name of the file you would like to open including the extension:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="fileName"><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Open File" name="fileOpen">
        </form>
    </body>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['fileInsert'])) {

        $fileInput = $_POST['fileInput'];

        $myfile = fopen($_POST['fileName'], "w");

        fwrite($myfile, $fileInput);
        fclose($myfile);

        echo "Done! <br />";

    }

    if(isset($_POST['fileOpen'])) {

        $fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
        echo str_ireplace("None", $fileName, "<h3>Currently open: None</h3><br />");

        if (is_file($fileName)) {
            echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
            echo "<label for='fileInput'>File is open!<br />Insert up to 40 characters:</label><br />";
            echo "<input type='text' name='fileInput' maxlength='40'><br />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='fileName' value='$fileName' >";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='fileInsert'><br /><br />";
            echo "</form>";


        }
        else {
            echo "File does not exist. <br /><br />";

            echo "<a href='start.php'><button>Return to Homepage</button></a>";
        }

    }

    else {
        echo "<h3>Currently open: None</h3><br />";
    }

    ?>

</html>
```

I cut the $_POST['fileInsert'] outside of the $_POST['fileOpen'] if because when we get this we don't get that, and I have added a hidden input field in
the 2nd form named fileInput which I use in the if of $_POST['fileInsert'] I need to know the file name which was also lost since the first post!

This method will also print the "Currently open:none" at the end after the Done!

BTW: this will overwrite your files! use 'a' instead of 'w' to add to files.